# pointwise convergence definition

Tags: convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I need some help to clarify with the idea of pointwise convergence.

The condition for pointwise convergence is usually given that if the limit of $f_n$ exists for each $x$ $\in$ $A$.

In Stephen Abbott's Understanding Analysis book, to show comparison with uniform convergence, the pointwise convergence definition is given as: " $f_n$ converges pointwise on $A$ to a limit function $f$ defined on $A$ if, for every $\epsilon>0$ and $x$ $\in$ $A$, there exists an $N$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ (can be dependent on $x$) such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ whenever $n$ $\geq$ $N$."

Taking an example of $x/(x+n)$, $x\geq0$, we can see the limit is $0$ holds for all $x\geq0$, but when evaluating it in terms of finding epsilon, $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ can only be bounded with $\epsilon\geq1$, isn't this contradict with the book's definition? but how can we explain the condition of limit exists? Does this example have pointwise convergence after all?

Comment: It does converge pointwise to $0$. $\frac  x {x+n}<\epsilon$ whenever $n >\frac {1-\epsilon} {\epsilon} x$.

Comment: I get the idea behind this, but in terms of 'convergence' doesn't it require $f_n$ to be bounded by every $\epsilon$ given a suitable $n$, for both pointwise and uniform case? Since choosing any $n$ does not allow $f_n$ to be bounded if we let $\epsilon$ $\in$ $(0,1)$, can we still say its 'convergence' at all?

Comment: $(f_n(x))$ is bounded for fixed $x$. The function $f_n$ need not be a bounded function.

Comment: You admit that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x}{x+n} = 0$ for all $x \ge 0$. By definition of the limit, that means for every $x \ge 0$, [for all $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $N$ such that if $n  > N$, then $|\frac{x}{x+n} - 0| < \epsilon$]. This is exactly the condition you gave for pointwise convergence. Since $x,\epsilon$ are defined before $N$, $N$ can be different for different $x$ and different $\epsilon$. How do you claim then that it only holds for $\epsilon \ge 1$?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between pointwise and uniform convergence is that the choice of $N \in \mathbb N$ depends on the choices of both $x$ and $\varepsilon$ in the case of pointwise convergence, while it only depends on $\varepsilon$ in the case of uniform convergence. That is, in the case of uniform convergence, there will exist an $N$ for each $\varepsilon$ such that convergence is “uniform” (or $N$ is the same) for each $x$.

In your example, only pointwise convergence is possible, since the choice of $N$ will always depend on both $x$ and $\varepsilon$.